# Visual Studio 2012 cursor jumping to begin of line after mbox “Edit and continue” showing

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2010 position of cursor remembered always. In Visual Studio 2012 when application is running and I press Enter VS shows me a message "Edit and continue"

[image]

After I press OK cursor jumping from previous position to start of line

I expect after showing message "Edit and continue" if reason is pressing Enter (not letter - in this case cursor saving its position) cursor not to go to the begin of editing line. In VS 2010 cursor saving its position in both cases (Enter or some letter pressed)

It is very annoying! May be it is feature, but I can not find option to turn it off. Or may be it is bug

Visual Studio 2012 Update 3

Comment: so what u need instead of cursor moving to the start of line,you need the position of cursor to be placed at the last saved point?

Comment: Yes!)) As in Visula Studio 2010